# How to fix: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider while running pyspark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to submit a pyspark job in my Mac machine. The use case is to upload the data frame created to S3 in CSV format. I am getting the below error when submitting the job.

People are suggesting to build some [Uber](https://github.com/amazon-archives/kinesis-storm-spout/issues/8) jar but I don't have any knowledge of Java. What can I try to solve this?

**spark-submit**

```
spark-submit --jars /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar,/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/jets3t-0.9.4.jar,/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.11.789.jar ./main.py
```

**Error:**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:524)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Code:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
df.write.parquet('s3a://<path>',mode="overwrite")
```

Comment: Can someone help me on this?